# How to change the background color of the checkbox to black?

Tags: css

currently I have encountered a project that needs to change the background color of the input checkbox to black. I searched for some information on the Internet but I still can’t successfully change the color. Would you like to help me find out what went wrong?

```css
 input[type=checkbox] {
   background-color: #222;
   padding: 3px 6px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   color: #fff;
   user-select: none; /* 防止文字被滑鼠選取反白 */
  }

  input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
     display: inline-block;
    content:"";
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#222;
}

/* input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
  content: "X";
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align:center;
} */
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"><label for="enter-send" class="enter-send"> Enter </label>
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at this question with its answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css

Answer (score 2):

You have to write custom CSS to style checkboxes.

```css
/* This css is for normalizing styles. You can skip this. */
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.new {
  padding: 50px;
}

.form-group {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.form-group input {
  padding: 0;
  height: initial;
  width: initial;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-group label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-group label:before {
  content:'';
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.form-group input:checked + label:before {
  background: black;
}

.form-group input:checked + label:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 9px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 14px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="new">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" id="html">
      <label for="html">HTML</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" id="css">
      <label for="css">CSS</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" id="javascript">
      <label for="javascript">Javascript</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```